# Converting C code to x86-64 bit Assembly?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, nasm

I am trying to create a random letter generator for my string and I've been given a C code and will have to convert it into Assembly language for my program. I'm doing this in ***x86-64 bit NASM assembly language***. I'm supposed to be using only system calls and not C/C++ function calls.
Here's the C/C++ code that I've got to convert:

```
int genran(int x,int y)
{
    int a = 0;
    a = a + x * 1103515245 + 12345;
    return (unsigned int)(a / 65536) % (y + 1); 
}
```

I am new to Assembly and any help is appreciated, here's what I've got so far. I know its somewhat wrong but I will be working on improving it:

```
            section .data
    string          db  "The random string is generated below: "
    len_string      equ  $-string
    a               dd  0
    x               dd  ?
    y               dd  ?
    rem             dd  0
            section .bss
    string_buff     resb    21  ;Our string's length is 20 characters
            section .txt
            global main
    main:
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        mov rsi, string     
        mov rdx, len_string
        syscall

        mov rax, a
        mov rbx, x      ;we have to come up with a value of x?
        mul rbx, 1103515245
        add rbx, 12345
        mov rax, rbx
        div rax, 65536
        mov rdx, y      ;we have to come up with a value of y?
        add rdx, 1
        ;mod rax, rdx
        ;ret
exit: 
      mov rax, 60
      xor rdi, rdi
      syscall
```

Comment: Note that `int` is a 32-bit type in x86-64 calling conventions; no need to use 64-bit registers, only 32-bit.  The C even explicitly uses `unsigned` to make wrapping well-defined. although it should have used unsigned the whole time; `x * 1103515245 + 12345` depends on 32-bit wrap-around, but in C for signed `int` that's undefined behaviour.  Also, `a`, `x,` and `y` are local vars, not global/static, so they should be in registers only, not labels and `dd`.  (Also `mov reg, symbol` puts the address in the register in NASM syntax, so if you did want globals you need `[a]`.)  Among other errors.

Comment: no unfortunately the assignment instructions mention it to be done in 64-bit and not 32-bit strictly. I'll try using the [a] instead of the a to store the data and not its address

Comment: @Peter do you know what values should go into x and y? What I feel is that x could be the ASCII char values and y as 20 i.e the max limit of the string, am I correct?

Comment: Are you sure they mean 64-bit integers, not just that it has to be 64-bit code?  But even so, `[x]` is still not matching the C; your C doesn't have any static storage. https://godbolt.org/z/Ebrdra.  Look at compiler output for an example, using `unsigned long long` or `uint64_t`.  (Also, `dd` is 4 bytes, a 64-bit register is 8 bytes, if you were going to use static storage).

Comment: Although perhaps the C is *supposed* to have used `static uint64_t a` to keep state across calls for this [LCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator)?  Or else `x` is supposed to be the previous random value, feeding it back into the function to generate another.  `y` is obviously the range of random number to generate, that's why they're using it as `random_number % (y+1)` to get a random number from [0..y], with a nearly uniform distribution.  (Not perfect unless `y+1` divides 2^32 exactly.)

Comment: So `y` can certainly come from a command line input.

Comment: I think it was 64-bit code. And the dd part, I was trying to assign a dword/quadword because the values of a, x and y might be 8-9 digits long and not considering the byte size.

Comment: We are just printing a string with 20 random letters every time the program runs, and not letting the user input anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
    mov rax, rbx
    div rax, 65536
```

Please read the instructions; this doesn't exist. `div` is an opcode that only takes one argument. The code should look like

```
    mov rax, rbx
    xor rdx, rdx ; Div takes rdx:rax as an implicit 128 bit argument.
    mov rcx, 65536
    div rcx
```

At this skill level I don't recommend trying to use `read` or write system calls. I very much instead recommend calling the C standard library until you get the hang of it. `read` and `write` have too many gotchas. You will want to write them *once* and include them in a mini-library any more assembly work you do.

We can skip `read` by taking argument off the command line as follows:

```
    mov rbx, [rsp + 16] ; argv[1]
```

Unless I'm very much mistaken, the first thing on the stack is `argc`, and then `argv[0]`, then `argv[1]`, ...

Comment: The OP is writing a `main`, not `_start`, so EDI=argc, RSI=`char **argv`.  No stack args.  `mov rdx, [rsi+8]` will load `argv[1]` into RDX, ready to dereference with `movzx eax, byte [rdx]` to get `argv[1][0]`, the first byte of the first arg.  (Assuming `argc>1`, otherwise `argv[1]` is NULL.)

Comment: Oh I see, I misunderstood div to be similar to add. Also, is my other stuff correct or was it just the div that was needed to be corrected? @Joshua  And I believe there's 20 characters and 1 extra is for the new line thats y string_buff is 21 [Edit: Nvm, I didn't get the argc part]

Comment: `div` has no immediate form, so `div 65536` won't work either.  But either way it is silly to use `div` when dividing by a constant power of 2; use a right shift instead.

Comment: unfortunately no Jumps or loops and also no push, pop, ret functions. wdym by right-shift ?@Nate

Comment: Like C's `>>` operator.  Think about what it does arithmetically. The instruction is `shr` or `sar` depending on whether it should be signed or unsigned.

Comment: @PeterCordes: lol fooled myself. Although if you aren't linking against libc you can call the entry point whatever you want.